# How do I filter on a field in a related object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

If I try to filter on a field in a related object then Tastypie returns an error. For example, running

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
     "http://localhost:8080/wordgame/api/v1/rounds/?format=json&players__username=moe"
```

returns "Lookups are not allowed more than one level deep on the 'players' field." Essentially, I am trying to do what I can currently do in the Django shell:

```
Round.objects.all().filter(players__username=moe.username)
```

I am using the following code, which I simplified for brevity:

```
# wordgame/api.py which has tastypie resources
class RoundResource(ModelResource):
    players = fields.ManyToManyField(UserResource, 'players',full=True)
    . . .

    class Meta:
        queryset = Round.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'rounds'
        filtering = {
            'players': ALL,
        }

class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'players'
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }

# wordgame/models.py which has Django models
class Round(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    . . .
```

I'm assuming that because UserResource defines a filter on the field 'username' that this should work but it does not. I even attempted to add "players__username" to the filter in RoundResource, however this did not work either.

I read about [basic filtering in the docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) and looked at the code on GitHub however there doesn't seem to be anything for this. I also took a look at the [advanced filtering documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering) and it doesn't seem to fit my use case. I've looked at the Tastypie code on GitHub but don't understand it enough to figure out if 1) I am doing this wrong, or 2) what to override to get this to work.

Comment: I assume `ManyToManyField` is a typo; [the Tastypie docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html) have it as `fields.ToManyField`

Comment: @supervacuo ManyToMany is supported in the current version as a subclass to ToManyField. You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py#L768).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently, you need to specifically white-list the relation-spanning lookups in your `filtering` line, like this:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'players'
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

At least, I *think* that's the right place to put it. The [relevant docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) are fairly slim on examples. A Tastypie ticket, though, [suggests this should work](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering).

Comment: Thanks! Changing 'ALL' to 'ALL_WITH_RELATIONS' in the RoundResource class worked. I can now filter the rounds by username. A little more doc, or maybe a better eye (on my part), would have picked up on this.