# Filtering Error: Lookups are not allowed more than one level deep

Tags: django, tastypie

From looking around at what others are doing this should be working, but I an error saying:

> Lookups are not allowed more than one level deep on the 'photos' field.

Here is the code that I have.  I've tried a few slight variations with how I set things up but I've had no luck.

```
class CollectionResource(ModelResource):
    photos = fields.ToManyField('photoproject.apps.kit.api.PhotoResource', 'photo_set', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'collection'

        queryset = Collection.objects.all()

        filtering = {
            'name': ['exact'],
            'photos': ALL
        }

class PhotoResource(ModelResource):
    collection = fields.ToOneField(CollectionResource, 'collection')

    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'photo'

        queryset = Photo.objects.all()

        filtering = {
            'id': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

And what I'm trying to query is:

```
/api/v1/collection/?photos__id=2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905206/how-do-i-filter-on-a-field-in-a-related-object#11907741), try changing ALL to ALL_WITH_RELATIONS for "photos":

```
class CollectionResource(ModelResource):
    photos = fields.ToManyField('photoproject.apps.kit.api.PhotoResource', 'photo_set', null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'collection'

        queryset = Collection.objects.all()

        filtering = {
            'name': ['exact'],
            'photos': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

Comment: I have tried that but then I was getting an error saying that "photo_set could not be found in the field list" and it would list off the fields in my photos table.

Comment: @Marcin What field on your PhotoResource model is the ManyToMany field? Right now, the second argument in your ToManyField ([which is the attribute argument](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/fields.py#L422)) is set to "photo_set". This means that it is looking at PhotoResource().photo_set as the M2M field.

Comment: Thanks Michael B.  I've managed to get it working after that comment! :)