# Django Tastypie: Filtering by ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I would like Django Tastypie to return a query filtered by a ForeignKey. Here are my two models:

```
class Origin(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=1024)

class Fruits(models.Model):
    origin      = models.ForeignKey(Origin)
    fruit_name  = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    is_sweet    = models.BooleanField()
    quantity    = models.IntegerField()
```

Based on the documentation [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#basic-filtering), I'm using the following resources.py:

```
class FruitResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Fruits.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']      
        filtering = {
            "origin": ('exact',)
            }
```

This is the URL I'm trying to access:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/fruit/?format=json&origin__country=Nepal
```

Accessing that URL returns the following output:

```
{
  "meta": 
    {
      "limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 2}, "objects": 
        [
          {"fruit_name": "Apple", "id": 1, "is_sweet": true, "quantity": 10, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/fruit/1/"}, 
          {"fruit_name": "Banana", "id": 2, "is_sweet": true, "quantity": 10, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/fruit/2/"}
        ]
}
```

I should mention that I get the same output using this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/fruit/?format=json
```

What is the correct way to get a list of Fruits objects by specifying the country attribute of the Origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084821/filtering-error-lookups-are-not-allowed-more-than-one-level-deep). I'm listing the final code here for the benefit of others.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, fields, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

from fruits.models import Fruits
from origin.models import Origin

class OriginResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Origin.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'origin'
        filtering = {
            "country": ('exact',)
            }

class FruitResource(ModelResource):
    origin = fields.ForeignKey(OriginResource, 'origin', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Fruits.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        filtering = {
            "origin": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            }
```

With this code, if I hit `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/fruit/?format=json&origin__country=Nepal` , I get the following expected output:

```
{"meta": 
  {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1},
   "objects": [{
         "fruit_name": "Apple", "id": 1, "is_sweet": true, "origin":
         {"country": "Nepal", "id": 3, "resource_uri": ""},
         "quantity": 10, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/fruit/1/"
    }]
}
```